# Passing logical operator as parameter

Tags: swift

Given a trivial code:

```
func f(_ a: Bool, _ b: Bool) {
    print(a || b)
}
f(false, false)
```

I'm trying to pass operation as parameter:

```
func g(_ a: Bool, _ b: Bool, _ op: (Bool, Bool) -> Bool) {
    print(op(a, b))
}
g(false, false, ||)
```

However it appears that operator `||` is not that simple:

> error: cannot convert value of type '(Bool, @autoclosure () throws -> Bool) throws -> Bool' to expected argument type '(Bool, Bool) -> Bool'

Attempting to change to

```
func g(_ a: Bool, _ b: Bool, _ op: (Bool, @autoclosure () throws -> Bool) throws -> Bool) {
    print(op(a, b))
}
g(false, false, ||)
```

results in

> error: call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled

How on earth can I pass `||` as parameter without dealing with `try/catch` stuff?

Comment: I think `||` is an autoclosure because it is a short-circuit operator. The right hand side is automatically wrapped in a closure so that it does not get evaluated if the left hand side evaluates to `true`. It is marked `throws` because the right hand side can error during evaluation.

Comment: `print(try? op(a, b))` or `print((try? op(a, b)) ?? false)`. That will ignore any errors.

Comment: Indeed, all you have to do is look at the declaration in the Swift header: `public static func || (lhs: Bool, rhs: @autoclosure () throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Bool`. Obviously, you cannot not "deal with `try/catch` stuff"; that "stuff" is built in.

Comment: You could just make the signature of the third parameter of `g` match the signature of `||`: `func g(_ a: Bool, _ b: Bool, _ op: (Bool, @autoclosure () throws -> Bool) throws -> Bool)`. That will allow you to pass either `||` or `&&` in this slot. Of course, whether that is useful depends on what you are _really_ trying to do, which you have not explained to us.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a version of `g` that compiles cleanly from your specified call:

```
func g(_ a: Bool, _ b: Bool, _ op: (Bool, @autoclosure () throws -> Bool) throws -> Bool) {
    print((try? op(a, b)) as Any)
}
g(false, false, ||)
```

But whether that is useful for your real use case is anybody's guess, as you have not explained what that use case is.

Answer (score 2):

Swift’s `||` and `&&` are short-circuit operators, meaning that if the left-hand side evaluates to true (respectively, false), then the right-hand side is not evaluated. The `@autoclosure` attribute automatically wraps its object in a closure, which allows you to defer execution of that object. For example:

```
func or(_ lhs: Bool, _ rhs: @autoclosure () -> Bool) -> Bool {
    if lhs {
        return true
    } else {
        return rhs()
    }
}

print(or(true, 1/0.0 == 0))
```

This example shows what `@autoclosure` does and why `||` and `&&` use it.

To see why the right hand side should be marked `throws`, consider

```
func f() -> Bool throws {
    return true
}

or(true, f())  // won’t compile because f throws
```

Hopefully this explains why the right-hand side is a throwing autoclosure in the first place, and why Swift requires that this throwing information be in `||`’s type signature, and in the type signature of any function that takes it as a parameter.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks all guys, I appreciate your ideas, now I realise that `||` is really a beast, but dealing with `try` is overkill.
So I decided just to pass the operation explicitly:

```
g(false, false, {
    (a: Bool, b: Bool) -> Bool in
    a || b
})
```

Comment: You could simplify that down to `g(false, false, { $0 || $1 })`